# Allow Lambda to be invoked by all EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Is it possible to allow a lambda to be invoked by all EC2 instance without giving any specific permissions for this on the EC2 side?

For this I tried to add a the following **ressource-based policy** to my lambda function, hoping it will give permission to all my EC2 instances to invoke it:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "InvokeLambdaFunction",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:myLambdaFunction",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:123456789012:instance/*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However when I invoke my lambda using the aws CLI from within an EC2 instance, I get an access denied:

```
sh-4.2$ aws lambda invoke --function-name "myLambdaFunction" --payload "{\"instance-id\":\"$EC2_INSTANCE_ID\"}" --region eu-west-1 response.json
```

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Invoke
> operation: User:
> arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup/i-06e731b382734dc8f
> is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource:
> arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:myLambdaFunction
> because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction
> action

Am I missing something here or is this simply not possible?

Comment: The error message shown mentions the `AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup` role. Why are you assuming this role? What policies does this role have?

Comment: `AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup` is a role managed by AWS I believe, it simply allows me to connect to the instance using SSM or run SSM documents on it.
It has the following attached policies (AWS managed): `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore`, `AmazonSSMDirectoryServiceAccess`

Comment: It seems, you are using SSM Session Manager to connect with EC2 shell, and at that moment, AWS CLI is using SSM Role instead of EC2 Instance IAM Role. Hence, you should add the SSM role ARN also in the Lambda Resource Policy.

Comment: @AnkushJain What is SSM Role in this case? Because I tried running `aws sts get-caller-identity` from within my EC2 while connected through SSM and I get the response `arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup/i-06e731b382734dc8f` so I believe it is using the EC2 instance profile, no?

Comment: @Mit94 what is the name of the actual role attached to the instance?

Comment: @Mit94 - No, that does not seem to be EC2 instance role. To check EC2 instance IAM role, run this command:   `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info`

Comment: @Paolo AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup

Comment: @AnkushJain I get `"InstanceProfileArn" : "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instance-profile/AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup"`. Since my aws command also returned `AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup` I believe it is using the right instance profile?

Comment: Yeah, this looks correct now. But your error says **because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action**. So, it means, this role should have IAM policy to invoke the role. Now, you want that all EC2 should have the permission to invoke the lambda, so in that case, you can attach the same role to all the EC2s you want to grant this access.

Comment: @AnkushJain In my case I want to allow the lambda invokation without tweaking the existing EC2 roles (because there's a lot of them and I don't manage them all). I understand that this is not possible?

Comment: EC2 needs an identity-based policy to invoke lambda, it is not possible only with resource -based policies